# C# winform, Can I access Controls Inside a GroupBox like this: myGroupBox.InnerTextBox.Text "someText";?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `GroupBox` which has 3 `TextBoxes` and 3 `Labels` 
the name of the group box is TextInfoGroupBox ..
I'm trying to access the textBoxes inside it, but I just don't seem to know how ..
I tried something like:

```
TextInfoGroupBox.innerTextbox;
TextInfoGroupBox.Controls.GetChildControl;
```

Both of these didn't pop up in the intellisence ..
how can i reach them, set and get data from them ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access them just like any other control:

```
innerTextBox
```

The Visual Studio designer generates a field for each control you put in your form, regardless of nesting.

Comment: Yes, I know that, But the problem is that I'm trying to pass the GroupBox to the constructor of another form, and there, I wanna reach those text boxes ..

Comment: Then you need to `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Controls` collection for this purpose. You will need to know exactly what item in that collection is your TextBox. If there are only 3 textboxes in your groupbox you can use

```
groupBox.Controls[0], groupBox.Controls[1], groupBox.Controls[2]
```

to access your items or just use their respective names.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have direct access to innerTextBox for some reason, you can always go hunting:

```
        TextBox myTextBox = null;

        Control[] controls = TextInfoGroupBox.Controls.Find("InnerTextBoxName", true);
        foreach (Control c in controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                myTextBox = c as TextBox;
                break;
            }
        }
```

At the end of this , if myTextBox is null, it couldn't be found (obviously).  Hopefully you don't structure it so that there would be multiple entries.

You could also create some cute extension methods:

```
public static Control FindControl(this Control parent, string name)
{
    if (parent == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return null;
    }

    Control[] controls = parent.Controls.Find(name, true);
    if (controls.Length > 0)
    {
        return controls[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static T FindControl<T>(this Control parent, string name) where T : class
{
    if (parent == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return null;
    }

    Control[] controls = parent.Controls.Find(name, true);
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        if (c is T)
        {
            return c as T;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And you could simply call them as

```
        Control c = TextInfoGroupBox.FindControl("MyTextBox");
        TextBox tb = TextInfoGroupBox.FindControl<TextBox>("MytextBox");
```